# Forward parameter packs but always combine N parameters

Tags: c++

Is there a simple way to transform and forward parameter packs, preferably without recursion in C++17? By transform I mean, to combine 2 adjacent parameters as one.

```cpp
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct CombinedType {
    T1 v1;
    T2 v2;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
void print_combined(CombinedType<T1, T2> v)
{
    std::cout << v.v1 << ", " << v.v2 << "\n";
}

// Does the work and contains the actual implementation
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename... Types>
void do_combined(CombinedType<T1, T2> c, Types ... args)
{
    print_combined(c);
    print_combined(args...);
}

// Shall be only a forwarder to keep legacy code working
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename... Types>
void do_single(T1 v1, T2 v2, Types... remaining)
{
    do_combined(CombinedType<T1, T2>{v1, v2});
    do_combined(CombinedType<Types...>{remaining}...);
}

int main()
{
    // Arguments are not necessarily of the same type
    do_single('1', 2, "3", 4u, std::string("5"), '6');
}
```

Above code does not compile, but you may ge the idea.

EDIT: If there is an elegant way to achieve that with recursion, I am open to it.

Comment: Why do you want to do it without recursion? With recursion, it's trivial.

Comment: I thought it would be easier to comprehend if everything was in a single function.

Comment: Single function requirement != recursive function requirement. Single function is enough for a recursive implementation.

Comment: Good point. I will lift the constraint then.

Comment: Added a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it relatively simple since c++17/c++20, using parameter packs, local template lambda, fold expression and tuples:

```
template<typename F, typename... Ts>
void for_pairs_tup(F f, std::tuple<Ts...> tup)
{
    [&]<size_t... is>(std::index_sequence<is...>) {
        ((f(std::get<is * 2>(tup), std::get<is * 2 + 1>(tup))), ...);
    }(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts) / 2>());
}

template<typename F, typename... Ts>
void for_pairs(F f, const Ts&... ts)
{
    for_pairs_tup(std::move(f), std::make_tuple(ts...));
}

// call it like:
    for_pairs(
        [](auto a, auto b) {
            std::cout << a << ", " << b << std::endl;
        },
        '1', 2, "3", 4u, std::string("5"), '6'
    );
```

Comment: Please note that lambda templates are available only since C++20.

Comment: @Bob__ yes, thanks for the note (modified), if you need without, of course it's possible to delegate to a template function instead of lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Without non-recursive solution requirement, the implementation is pretty simple with `if constexpr`:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename... Types>
void do_single(T1 v1, T2 v2, Types... remaining)
{
    print_combined(CombinedType<T1, T2>{v1, v2});
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Types) > 0)
        do_single(remaining...);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ezsb6Gr9Y)